# Change text font color in Word document

Tags: c#, windows, ms-word

I wrote a small test word addon and I can't find a way to **change the font color** of a word. 
Here's my code:

```
var wordsList = this.Application.ActiveDocument.Words;
wordsList[i].Font.TextColor = WdColor.wdColorRed;
```

This won't compile because TextColor Property has no Setter (ReadOnly).

Comment: does the below work for you? if so, you can select the hollow checkmark next to the answer

Answer (score 7):

There are two ways to do it. You can either use `Font.ColorIndex` for simple choices or  `Font.Fill.ForeColor` for more extensive choices. Here's some VBA:

```
Sub ChangeColorThisWay()
    Dim s As Range: Set s = Selection.Range
    s.Font.Fill.ForeColor = WdColor.wdColorRed
End Sub
Sub ChangeColorThatWay()
    Dim s As Range: Set s = Selection.Range
    s.Font.ColorIndex = WdColorIndex.wdBrightGreen
End Sub
```

Note on the `Font.Fill.ForeColor` one, you also have access to the `RGB` property and can set the font to any non-constant color, like `s.Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 0)` sets it to yellow.

Answer (score 4):

You need to set `Font.ColorIndex = Word.WdColorIndex.wdRed`, not the `TextColor` property. Set the index to what you need and you are set.