# Change text backgroundcolor in Word

Tags: c#, office-interop, word-2007, office-addins

the situation:

- .net 3.5
- c# or vb.net(also tested)
- word 2007 add-in

I'm trying to set the Background Color of the text to a custom rgb color.

The code is the following:

```
Range r = this.Application.ActiveDocument.Range();
r.Text = "blabla";
r.Font.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor =(WdColor) Color.FromArgb(0, 214, 227,188).ToArgb();
```

At first it seems to work, except that the color is not the right one. It seems that whenever I set a custom color, it changes it to an existing WdColor constant. Having a look at the [doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.shading.backgroundpatterncolor.aspx), it says :

> Returns or sets the 24-bit color that's applied to the background of the Shading object. Can be any valid WdColor constant or a value returned by Visual Basic's RGB function.

So, my question is: does anybody has an idea of how it's supposed to work?

Thanx

Comment: Possible duplicate [change-text-font-color-in-word-document](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292007/change-text-font-color-in-word-document)

Comment: It says basically the same thing as the doc: use and index or a custom one but this is what is not working.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [ColorTranslator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yzwa1ke2.aspx)

```
Range r = this.Application.ActiveDocument.Range();
r.Text = "blabla";
r.Font.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor =(WdColor)ColorTranslator.ToOle(0, 214, 227,188);
```

Comment: The sample code does not work as given; I believe it is missing an intermediate method call: `ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.FromArgb(0, 214, 227,188));`. Perhaps a different .Net version?